# Can I revise W/L ratio at the LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, pspice

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to make spice simulation.

I have used PSPICE Lite edition, and I got to use this Lspice because of the limit of the PSPICE
(It has number limit to use component)

And I am trying to revise W or L size in LTspice, But it is hard to find it.

Can I adjust W or L size at the LTspice?

Comment: If you are lucky, the mosfet you want to simulate is already built in (there are some built-in).  If not, then you will need to dig in and make a model.  You can use some of the existing ones as templates.  There is a lot of information available in LTspiceHelp under M. MOSFET.  You can add a new device selectable using "Pick New MOSFET" in this file:
%HOMEPATH%\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.mos

Comment: LTspice is a free download so you can just try it yourself. Realize that W and L sizing needs to be supported by the **model** of the MOSFET that you're using. If can't make it work in LTSpice there's also Qucs: http://qucs.sourceforge.net/ which is also free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong symbol. You need to use `nmos4` for integrated circuit MOSFETs, as shown below.  Don't forget to connect the body terminal to the correct spot for each FET in your application.

[image]

Then if you rightclick on the symbol you can set the model name and the instance parameters.

[image]

Afterward, you can shift+rightclick the symbol and then double-click the `Vis.` square for the instance parameters so they show on the schematic.  If you do this, it also makes it easier to edit `L` and `W` later since you can just rightclick on the text directly.

[image]

Lastly, you should define a `.model` statement with non-default parameters.  See the LTspice help (press `F1` key) for more information about [M. MOSFET](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm).  The last image below is a rough representation of what a final schematic could look like.

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SamGibson I'm a newcomer here, And I didn't know the rule about accepting the answer when I like the answer. So If I have passed by this question omtting the pressing green-tick-mark button, you might feel a little bad feeling - like, he dosen't seem to appreciate my effort to reply the question even after getting what he wants. That's why I mentioned a word "rude"

Comment: @fluencer - Hi, Thanks for explaining :-) Relevant [help] pages include: as I linked before [What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](/help/accepted-answer). Basically, you can upvote any answers to show they are useful. When you get 15 "points" yourself, your votes will show. Also for any question you ask, you can "accept" one answer, to show that it solved your problem. Accepting an answer (it's optional, but considered "good manners" if it solved your problem) also indicates to other users that you don't need more answers.

Comment: @SamGibson haha I also voted your answer. Thanks for your instruction for using this websites. It will be very helpful to me :)